# Java Application Embed Google Maps

Tags: java, google-maps, system

Is there a way to embed Google Maps into A Java Desktop Application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JxMaps component, it wraps JavaScript layer and provides Java interface for interaction with Google Maps. It has `MapBrowser` swing component that can be easily inserted to any swing application.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps is a javascript-based api, so you could just embed a web view into your desktop app.

However, be aware that you will need to apply to Google for a license to do that. See the bottom of their licensing page at https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing

Comment: Thank you i worked that out, I am trying to use it on a project for my final year Software Engineering degree. Is there a way to use it for that purpose or would I have to purchase a License. IF not an alternative is Open Street Maps.